# How to call secure ssl REST web API in html javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an cross platform html5 javascript application. In that I have to fetch data from secure ssl enable web api. I am getting problem while calling this web api from server by sending response "access forbidden" when I disable the SSL on server it works fine. So to resolve this  I have to add client certificate while requesting/communicating with these API's. I have used both jquery.ajax and xmlhttmRequest to fetch data from server in Javascript but it gives error for web api where SSL implemented. Please let me know to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468220/calling-my-web-api-from-jquery-securely check this if it solves your issue.

Comment: thanks for response, unfortunately we are using SSL client certificate   to call web services not authentication token, sever reject my web api call if doesn't find Client certificate in request header with forbidden message.